# Mongo TTL and Change Events to return full document as cursor

Tags: python, mongodb

I looking to schedule a task when a document's datetime field hits that time, I've set that up using [TTL](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/). Problem is that according to [delete event](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/change-events/#delete-event) when I receive the cursor, the original document is not returned to the program. I still need the document (that is now deleted) on python stack since it contains other properties that are important to executing the task. Is there some kind of a workaround where I can get the document via change event without deleting it, or get the deleted document without having to do a query?

Comment: Store documents in two collections, look up the full document in the second collection using the id obtained from the first collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no workaround. The tools you've chosen are not sufficient for the job.

Replace the TTL index with a regular one and replace your ChangeStream listener with a cron job to run a worker every minute.

The worker will get all expired documents, do the job, and delete the documents from the collection either one by one or in batches.

It is more reliable, flexible and scalable approach comparing to the TTL + ChangeStream.

Comment: Starting in MongoDB version 6.0, how would you assess using TTL + ChangeStream + `fullDocumentBeforeChange` to satisfy the OP's question?